# how to separated the_content of post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have in post title, img and text. All I need to do, is put img to the top, then title, and then text of this post.

Anyone have any idea how to do this in wordpress?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: My own, I prepere php file and add all I found to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is the post "featured image" then separating and placing the three components is easy (see below).  However if your image is within the post then you may need a different approach.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: No, this post isnt featured image.. Thats why I`m looking for another solution.

Comment: Check out this post on pulling the first image from a post: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-a-post/

Comment: That`s it! Thank you very much! And the rest of active people.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at a single post then you will want to re-factor content.php located in your themes main directory.

This is the line that displays the featured image:

```
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

You'll want to play around and move that and some of the other parts of the code in this file.
Hope this helps!